# Python TypeError: unsupported operand types for +: 'tag' and 'str'

Tags: python, xml, curl

I am using numbers from a specific column of an excel document(csv) to populate a URL, from which cURL extracts XML and places into a new column of the outfile (also an excel document). This process is repeated for each id in the column. I cannot figure out why I am getting this error, as the output is in fact a string, and I do not see why you would not be able to concatenate it with a 'tab' buffer. I also thought I should ask this since I did not see any other questions relating this error to tags, maybe someone else can benefit from it as well. Anyway here is some code let me know if more information is needed, I have marked where the error happens (near the bottom):

```
outFile = open(tempFileName, 'w')
outFile.write('\t'.join(fancyHeaders) + '\n')
outFile.write('\t'.join(order) + '\n')
lastFN = False
for line in data:
if lastFN!=line['AppStatus'] and lastFN:
    outFile.write('\n')
for column in order:
    outFile.write(line[column] + '\t') #Error occurs here
lastFN = line['AppStatus']
outFile.write('\n')
xlApp.Workbooks.OpenText(tempFileName)

xlApp.Range("A1:Z9999").HorizontalAlignment = -4131
xlApp.Range("A1:Z9999").VerticalAlignment = -4160
xlApp.Range("A1:Z9999").WrapText = True
xlApp.Cells.RowHeight=12.75

xlApp.DisplayAlerts=False
xlApp.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs(outFileName)


xlApp.Quit()
xlApp.Visible = 0 # see note 2
del xlApp
```

Comment: could you please point out one line with the error?

Comment: `outFile.write(line[column] + '\t')`

Comment: Actually it's necessary for my company's firewall, so it is necessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if the line[column] is not string, you cannot concatenate it, then try to change:

```
str(line[column] + '\t')
```

into:

```
str(line[column]) + '\t'
```

Answer (score 3):

Couldn't you just write it that way ?

```
outFile.write(str(line[column]) + '\t')
```